# Group by to club multiple column value in hive to one column

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am trying to club multiple column value to one column based on group by key. Basically I will use this to create nested JSON using spark 1.6 dataframe api.

Sample Input Table abc:-

```
a     b     c       d       e       f       g
---------------------------------------------
aa    bb    cc      dd      ee      ff      gg
aa    bb    cc1     dd1     ee1     ff1     gg1
aa    bb    cc2     dd2     ee2     ff2     gg2
aa1   bb1   cc3     dd3     ee3     ff3     gg3
aa1   bb1   cc4     dd4     ee4     ff4     gg4
```

final output group by a,b :-

```
aa      bb      {{cc,dd,ee,ff,gg},{cc1,dd1,ee1,ff1,gg1},{cc2,dd2,ee2,ff2,gg2}}
aa1     bb1     {{cc3,dd3,ee3,ff3,gg3},{cc4,dd4,ee4,ff4,gg4}}
```

I tried using collect_list but it can only group one column. Don't know how to group multiple column together. I tried using concat string and then use collect on it but I will loose schema mapping as I have to finally dump it in json format. Clubbing the colunms in form of map or struct will also work. Please suggest some elegant approach/solution to this problem. Thanks
Note : Using Spark 1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both queries work with `sqlContext.sql ("select ...");`

---

```
select      a,b
           ,collect_list(array(c,d,e,f,g))

from        abc

group by    a,b
;
```

---

```
+-----+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aa  | bb  | [["cc","dd","ee","ff","gg"],["cc1","dd1","ee1","ff1","gg1"],["cc2","dd2","ee2","ff2","gg2"]] |
+-----+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aa1 | bb1 | [["cc3","dd3","ee3","ff3","gg3"],["cc4","dd4","ee4","ff4","gg4"]]                            |
+-----+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

```
select      a,b
           ,collect_list(struct(c,d,e,f,g))

from        abc

group by    a,b
;
```

---

```
+-----+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aa  | bb  | [{"col1":"cc","col2":"dd","col3":"ee","col4":"ff","col5":"gg"},{"col1":"cc1","col2":"dd1","col3":"ee1","col4":"ff1","col5":"gg1"},{"col1":"cc2","col2":"dd2","col3":"ee2","col4":"ff2","col5":"gg2"}] |
+-----+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aa1 | bb1 | [{"col1":"cc3","col2":"dd3","col3":"ee3","col4":"ff3","col5":"gg3"},{"col1":"cc4","col2":"dd4","col3":"ee4","col4":"ff4","col5":"gg4"}]                                                               |
+-----+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Spark demo

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ spark-shell --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.0
      /_/

Type --help for more information.
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

---

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ spark-shell

scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from abc").show;
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  f|  g|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| aa| bb| cc| dd| ee| ff| gg|
| aa| bb|cc1|dd1|ee1|ff1|gg1|
| aa| bb|cc2|dd2|ee2|ff2|gg2|
|aa1|bb1|cc3|dd3|ee3|ff3|gg3|
|aa1|bb1|cc4|dd4|ee4|ff4|gg4|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+


scala> sqlContext.sql("select a,b,collect_list(array(c,d,e,f,g)) from abc group by a,b").show;
+---+---+--------------------+                                                  
|  a|  b|                 _c2|
+---+---+--------------------+
|aa1|bb1|[[cc3, dd3, ee3, ...|
| aa| bb|[[cc, dd, ee, ff,...|
+---+---+--------------------+


scala> sqlContext.sql("select a,b,collect_list(struct(c,d,e,f,g)) from abc group by a,b").show;
+---+---+--------------------+                                                  
|  a|  b|                 _c2|
+---+---+--------------------+
|aa1|bb1|[[cc3,dd3,ee3,ff3...|
| aa| bb|[[cc,dd,ee,ff,gg]...|
+---+---+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But we are using Spark1.6 henc eit is not working. Even on hive it is giving exception FAILED: UDFArgumentTypeException Only primitive type arguments are accepted

Comment: collect_list(array(c,d,e,f,g)) or collect_list(struct(c,d,e,f,g)) works well with Spark 2.0 . But in spark 1.6 collect_list only support primitive type. Please suggest does any other workaround possible for this in spark 1.6.

Comment: This was tested successfully on spark 1.6

Comment: Seems like some path is missing on my spark installation which is causing this issue. Thanks for reply

Comment: Ashish, did you figure out your path problem?  If so, what was missing?